# Azure Kubernetes Service - can the Cluster Autoscaler get triggered even if I don't set autoscaling explicitly?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I am deploying a service to `Azure Kubernetes Service`.

The `Horizontal Pod Autoscaler` scales the number of pods, whereas the `Cluster Autoscaler` scales the number of nodes based on the number of pending pods. If my understanding is correct, if I don't set up autoscaling in my deployment file, the `HPA` won't get triggered, and only one pod will run; therefore, the `CA` won't get triggered either.

My question is - is there a scenario in `AKS` where the `CA` would get triggered, even without setting autoscaling in my deployment file?

Comment: I cannot see this being a programming question. At best it is configuration or a product query.  Or even testing as the goal would be to stress the single pod. There was nothing the "community" could provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is - is there a scenario in AKS where the CA would get triggered, even without setting autoscaling in my deployment file?

Cluster autoscaler is typically used together with the horizontal pod autoscaler. The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler increases or decreases the number of **pods** based on application demand, and the cluster autoscaler adjusts the number of **nodes** as needed to run those additional pods accordingly.

If your deployment does not have the capacity to automatically scale up or down via the **HPA**, **NOR** you don't manually increase number of pods to the level where no additional pods can run due to insufficient resource in your nodes then the **CA** would not be triggered therefore the answer is **NO**.

You might find [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-autoscaler) document from official azure docs helpful also.